# Yii - Downloaded zip file is corrupted

Tags: php, yii, zip, httprequest

Downloading a zip file from Yii is resulting in corrupted files within the zip. I am able to open the zip, search its contents, but the data is corrupted. Opening the zip file in the file explorer shows that the zip file is OK. The problem only shows up when downloading a file:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open($zipname, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)  === TRUE ){

    // add stuff to zip
    $res = $zip->addFile($a, $b);
}

Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile($zipname, file_get_contents($zipname), "application/zip", true);
```

I think the problem is with the $content argument to Yii's sendFile.

What should go in the content argument, so that the zip file is not corrupted?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `$zip->close();` before you try to send the file, see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Do you have any debugging or tracing running (CWebLogRoute / or Yii Debug Toolbar etc)? As these will output content at the end of your request which will corrupt some filetypes.

Comment: @WillemRenzema I had zip->close(), just forgot to copy it to the question.

Comment: @Stu Thanks for the suggestion, I ended up finding a solution. See answer. Thanks both for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($zipname));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($zipname);
        exit;
```